# Group and sum equal entries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, count, unique

I have a CSV file which contains multiple data in row common with other rows with its count. I have a requirement of counting all those unique traces and updating the existing count column with the updated unique data.

I have added the code which i tried but it is not giving the required output

```
final_count = combined_csv.groupby(['Context Event','Actual Event']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

Lets say Input Data is this--

```html
Context Event                       Actual Event        Frequency Count
FindApplication_Explorer.EXE LeftClick_Explorer.EXE         4
LeftClick_Explorer.EXE         FindApplication_chrome.exe     3
FindApplication_chrome.exe     FindApplication_Explorer.EXE 2
FindApplication_Explorer.EXE LeftClick_Explorer.EXE         1
FindApplication_Explorer.EXE LeftClick_Explorer.EXE         2
FindApplication_chrome.exe     FindApplication_Explorer.EXE 2
```

Output I want this---

```html
Context Event                     Actual Event       Frequency Count
FindApplication_Explorer.EXE LeftClick_Explorer.EXE          7
LeftClick_Explorer.EXE        FindApplication_chrome.exe      3
FindApplication_chrome.exe    FindApplication_Explorer.EXE      4
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following snippet to get the desired result. What's important here to use is first of to specify the CSV Seperator which is a `\t (TAB)` in your case and secondly to use `skipinitialspace` which will remove trailing whitespaces from column names.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

input_string = StringIO(
  """
  Context Event\t                       Actual Event\t         Frequency Count\t
  FindApplication_Explorer.EXE\t    LeftClick_Explorer.EXE\t          4\t
  LeftClick_Explorer.EXE\t          FindApplication_chrome.exe\t      3\t
  FindApplication_chrome.exe\t      FindApplication_Explorer.EXE\t    2\t
  FindApplication_Explorer.EXE\t    LeftClick_Explorer.EXE\t          1\t
  FindApplication_Explorer.EXE\t    LeftClick_Explorer.EXE\t          2\t
  FindApplication_chrome.exe\t      FindApplication_Explorer.EXE\t    2\t
  """
)


dataframe = pandas.read_csv(input_string, sep="\t", skipinitialspace=True)
dataframe.set_index(['Context Event', 'Actual Event'])
print(
    dataframe.groupby(
      [
        'Context Event',
        'Actual Event']
    )['Frequency Count'].sum().reset_index(name='Total Amount')
)
```

The output I get is the following

```
                  Context Event                  Actual Event  My Sum
0  FindApplication_Explorer.EXE        LeftClick_Explorer.EXE       7
1    FindApplication_chrome.exe  FindApplication_Explorer.EXE       4
2        LeftClick_Explorer.EXE    FindApplication_chrome.exe       3
```

Please use the following [repl.it link](https://repl.it/@FrankLazzarini/Pandas-groupbysum) to illustrate or tinker around with this example.

Comment: I can't put data in csv data in code because it contains around 10,000 rows.So there is any other way to get the output.

Comment: You could read the csv from a file like so `dataframe = pandas.read_csv("my_filename.csv", sep="\t", skipinitialspace=True)`, does that help?

Comment: I've edited my answer however I renamed the sum column name in the returned dataframe to `My Sum` just to make it clear that this is actually a new column.

Comment: Error KeyError: 'Context Event' while running this line dataframe.set_index(['Context Event', 'Actual Event'])

Comment: Yes due to copy/pasting the tabs between the columns got erased. I will update the solution again and place repl.it link as well.

Comment: And I want to write Output as CSV

Comment: Still not working for csv file it only runs when one add data input_string which is not possible because my csv file contain 10000 data rows.....

Comment: Ok I think the confusion here is somehow Tabs were introduces in your initial quesion. I've updated the repl.it example again, which is also reading from a local file now. How to apply this in jupyter I am not sure, you would need some way to access a local file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198637/discussion-between-flazzarini-and-ani).

Comment: See I even copy small snapshot of my csv data in repl.it with My_Csv file name thats the format of my csv file...

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

# Use anis csv file
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('ani_data.csv', sep=',')

print(dataframe)

dataframe.set_index(['Context Event', 'Actual Event'])
print(
dataframe.groupby(['Context Event','Actual Event'])['Frequency Count'].sum().reset_index(name='Count'))
```